# get an array of objects from php using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I have php file that return a list of objects from database.
this is the php code:

```
<?php
require_once('../connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $mydata = $json->addChild('category');
        $mydata->addChild('id',$row['id']);
        $mydata->addChild('name',$row['Name']);
         }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
     echo( json_encode ($json));
?>
```

and this is the result:

> {"category":[{"id":"1","name":"test"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"}]}

Now i want to get the list of categories in android, i tried to do it using this code but it always return empty list:

```
   public List<Category> getAllCategories(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://localhost/Android/Categories/Select_All_Categories" ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("TAG","response :"+response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray sts = null;
                            sts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("category");

                            for (int i = 0; i < sts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jo = sts.getJSONObject(i);
                                Category cc = new Category();
                                cc.setId(jo.getInt("id"));
                                cc.setName(jo.getString("name"));
                                ar.add(cc);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        return ar;
    }
```

can someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Update for diegoveloper: this is the code i used in my main.

```
MyListener listener = new MyListener() {
    @Override
    public void returnYourData(List<Category> list) {
        for(Category c:list){
            lc.add(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void returnError() {

    }
};


System.out.println(lc.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your request is asynchronous, you could use an Interface to return your data.

```
public void getAllCategories(final YourInterfaceListener listener){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://localhost/Android/Categories/Select_All_Categories" ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("TAG","response :"+response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray sts = null;
                            sts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("category");

                            for (int i = 0; i < sts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jo = sts.getJSONObject(i);
                                Category cc = new Category();
                                cc.setId(jo.getInt("id"));
                                cc.setName(jo.getString("name"));
                                ar.add(cc);
                            }
                            listener.returnYourData(ar);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            listener.returnError();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        listener.returnError();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Your interface:

```
public interface YourInterfaceListener {
   void returnYourData(List<Category> list);
   void returnError();
}
```

**UPDATE**

You are using an incorrect way to retrieve the data, check my "getAllCategories" method, is void.

Your data is received on the listener :

```
MyListener listener = new MyListener() {
    @Override
    public void returnYourData(List<Category> list) {
         // HERE YOU HAVE THE DATA, UPDATE YOUR UI HERE.
    }

    @Override
    public void returnError() {

    }
};
```

Comment: still getting an empty array

Comment: I don't think so, Could you update your code please?

Comment: i created the interface and copied your code in my class then i used this code to get the list in my main

Comment: Put your Main code, I want to check how you are doing

Comment: I updated my answer, please check and let me know if it works

Comment: i updated the code i used in my main, lc.size() still return a 0.

Comment: print : System.out.println(lc.size());   inside  returnYourData :)

Comment: or put your Activity class

Comment: ok i did that and now it doesnt show the print, i think the application didn't run the code inside returnYourData!

Comment: Put your activity class and I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Check your server response 1st. Run your php manually, using your browser. Then get its json response. If its empty or error, problem in your server or php. Sometimes those type of things happen in local host by blocking ports & etc. If it has a json array. use below methods to get its data. Those methods work perfect for me, I used in many applications.

```
 RequestQueue rq; //assign as a global variable
 String json_string; //assign as a global variable
 String url = "http://yourphpfilelink.php"; //assign as a global variable

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //call below functions inside oncreate

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        sendjsonrequest();
}

    public void sendjsonrequest(){
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //json_string = response.getString("server_response");
                            jsonget(response);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }});
                    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                }

             public void jsonget(JSONObject json_string1){
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = json_string1.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            int count = 0;
                            String name1,name2,name3;
                            msg="";
                            while (count<jsonArray.length()){
                                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                                name1 = JO.getString("name1");
                                name2 = JO.getString("name2");
                                name3 = JO.getString("name3");
                                msg = msg+"name1: " + name1 + "\nname2: "+ name2 + "\nname3: " + name3 + "C\n\n";
                                count++;        }
                            yourtextview.setText(msg);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  }
                    }
```